# Handle surrogates with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

When saving the data

```
data.to_csv(outp_file, encoding='utf-8')
```

I sometimes get errors like this

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position
>   233-234: surrogates not allowed

In python3 you can simply replace such characters

```
>> "abc\udc34xyz".encode('utf-8', 'replace').decode('utf-8')
'abc?xyz'
```

But here I have a dataframe with N rows and M columns. It's fine for me to remove rows with surrogates, but it's not fine to skip the whole dataframe.

The problem is I don't know in which rows and in which columns they are.

I am looking for a solution that could be applied in following way

```
try:
   data.to_csv(outp_file, encoding='utf-8')
except UnicodeEncodeError:
   # process data and save it without surrogates...
```

Any help?

Comment: couldn't you just use `applymap` to apply the python function to all cells individually before writing a csv?

Comment: and as always, it's better if you can provide a small sample dataframe for people to test their answers on.  and also, desired results.

Comment: @JohnE For now it seems the only possible solution, regardless it tells you "that's not the way you should do it". Often I deal with quite large dataframes having several millions of columns of text (and solution "just verify every piece of it" may not scale very well). Input is any dataframe (it may be quite large as I pointed out) with cell(s) containing surrogate characters like in my question. Desired result is that dataframe having surrogate characters replaced with "?" like in my question.

Answer (score 4):

```
for col in train.columns:
    if train[col].dtype==object:
        train[col]=train[col].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x==np.nan else str(x).encode('utf-8', 'replace').decode('utf-8'))
```

Try this. It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can open file yourself to fix this problem:

```
with open(outp_file, 'w', encoding='utf8', errors='replace') as f:
    data.to_csv(f)
```

Or if outp_file is a file-like object you can write manually:

```
outp_file.write(data.to_csv().encode('utf-8', 'replace').decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. The thing is that data is not in the file, but rather in the memory after being aggregated from sql tables.

Comment: @tarashypka Please take a look at the updated answer. Does this work for you?

Comment: Does not work with `to_feather`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your unicode inputs look like, nor why they occasionally have non-UTF16 codepoints that require a low surrogate like DC34. If your data mostly fits within USASCII, then `iconv` might offer a useful way to strip out inconvenient codepoints:

```
$ cat foo1.csv | iconv -c -f utf16 -t latin1 | iconv -f latin1 -t utf8 > foo2.csv
```

Have your application read the resulting output .csv.

If you look at `iconv --help` you will notice that `-c` indicates discard, plus there are a few other potentially helpful discard options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
for c in data:
    data[c] = [x.encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf-16') for x in data[c]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have created a function for this purpose based on the answer by Rahul Yadav.

```
import numpy as np
def surrogate_remover(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        if df[col].dtype==object:
            df[col]=df[col].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x==np.nan else str(x).encode('utf-8', 'replace').decode('utf-8'))
    return df
```

Then use this function and do a write.

```
df = surrogate_remover(df)
df.to_csv("example.csv")
```